# Identify logged user details inside a lightning component

Tags: lightning

Is there any way to get the logged user information inside a lightning component?
The lightning component displays an Iframe and I want

Comment: What you have tried so far? Can edit your question with those details as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that this is available in both Aura and LWC.

https://jayakrishnasfdc.wordpress.com/2019/01/13/get-current-user-id-information-in-lightning-web-components/

In Aura:

```
var userId = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id");
```

In LWC:

```
import userId from '@salesforce/user/Id';
```

Then, because you have userId, you can use LDS or your custom Apex code to get the data about the `User` object.